# How to display app's form to display at desired monitor when debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug my C# Windows form app, built with Visual Studio 2017 pro on Windows 10, the app window always displays on my main monitor, which is the middle monitor of my 3 monitors.

Is there a 'trick' to always open and display on the left-hand monitor?
(I want to use middle monitor to see the source code.)

If no trick, then I must program form's x,y to persist across debug sessions.

Comment: Try moving your mouse (quickly) to the monitor you want it to pop up on after hitting F5 or the play button. You can set the location manually, but you probably don't want to do that for release code (you can set a `#if DEBUG`).

Comment: Once you start debugging application, drag the application window to the desired monitor. Next time when you start debugging it will open in that monitor only..

Comment: Adding code in the form's Load event, bracketed with #if DEBUG, is not wrong.  Use the Screen class to know how to set the form's Location.  Writing code that is easily debuggable is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the form's startup location manually.

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

Then you should be able to find your other monitor and apply its' location to your current form using

```
Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
Point location = screens[0].Bounds.Location;
this.Left = location.X;
this.Top = location.Y;
```

I can't confirm that this is exactly what you need since I currently am not at a computer with multiple monitors but it should be something very close to this if I'm wrong.

Comment: Where would that code be put though?

Comment: Ah, putting it in the constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`, does the trick. I managed to use `Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position)` to always make my app open in the screen the user is 'looking at'. Dialogs opening on CenterScreen start position do this by default apparently.